# Compare date in java

Tags: java-8

I am getting `2040-11-01T00:00:00.000-05:00` this format date in String from server. I want to compare this date with today's date to check incoming date in response is after today.

How I can check it in `java8` way?

Comment: @possum No, `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here.

Comment: Do you want to compare the *date* or the *moment*?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

If you want to compare the moment represented by your text input against the current moment.

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2040-11-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" )
.toInstant()
.isAfter(
    Instant.now() 
)
```

## Details

Parse your input as a date with time-of-day on the context of an offset-from-UTC, an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. Then extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to see the same moment adjusted to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2040-11-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  // Offset of zero, as seen in UTC.
```

Get current moment. Compare.

```java
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
boolean isFuture = instant.isAfter( now ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, Can you plase also let me know if I want to compare my incoming string date to EST Current Time how can I compare?

Comment: @ppb The code shown in the Answer does that. `Instant.now` gets the current moment as seen in UTC. That would the same moment as derived from `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toInstant()`. Also, `EST` is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).